# Building a simple component for a 360 degree Image in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, 3d

I am attempting to build a React component that displays a 360 degree view of a product. I am attempting to convert [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/jQuery-Plugin-For-Draggable-360-Degrees-Product-Image-View-j360.html) script which uses jQuery to display a draggable 360 degree product image into a React component.

The way this script works is by first loading ~20 images of the product at each angle up to 360 degrees. Then, using jQuery, automatically switching the image based on mouse click and move event.

As a part of my React component I have managed to load the images from a folder and am trying to switch the image based on a mouse click and move event. Additionally, I have found [this](https://medium.com/@agm1984/use-react-to-make-a-photo-follow-the-mouse-aka-transform-perspective-or-tilt-7c38f1b3a623) article which creates a 3D perspective view of an image and has some useful functions for React synthetic events.

**How do I use a React synthetic event to capture mouse click and move event so I can switch to the next image in the array?**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {


  render() {
    // var foo = new Array(36);
    var N = 37; 
    var imageCount = Array.apply(null, {length: N}).map(Number.call, Number)
    imageCount.shift()
    console.log(imageCount)
    let images = imageCount.map( (name, index) => {
            return <img key={index} className="img-responsive" alt="" src={require(`./360-demo/${name}.jpg`)} />
        } );

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>

        {images}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Once I get a working component I plan to open source this code so others can also benefit.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Please ask a concrete question. Seeking for general advice is beyond the scope of stack overflow.

Comment: @trixn apologies - tried to clarify above what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the rotation start with `onMouseDown`, which means the dragging has to originate within the component. For movement and rotation stop, you can use `onMouseMove` and `onMouseUp`, but it might be better to attach to the document for that. Generally I wouldn't recommend ever touching the `document` in React, but with event handlers on the component, it won't detect movement outside of the component (like your jQuery one does).

The gist of it would be something like:

```
handleMouseDown = event => {
  this.setState({
    dragging: true,
    dragStart: event.screenX,
  });
};

handleMouseUp = () => {
  this.setState({ dragging: false });
};

handleMouseMove = event => {
  if (this.state.dragging) {
    const position = event.screenX;
    // <-- update your image index
  }
};

render = () => {
  return (
    <div onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}>
      {this.renderImage()}
    </div>
  );
};

componentDidMount = () => {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp, false);
};

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp, false);
};
```

Here is a sandbox with a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6v3491kxw3

Comment: Ok so awesome I got it all up and working but I'm running into an issue when I try to make numImages a prop that can be passed to the component. Sometimes the index gets calculated as NaN and the app crashes. Everything works great when I hardcode numImages but to be reusable I need to abstract numImages and the image directory as props.

You can check out the code here https://github.com/aldrinc/React360

Comment: Number divided by zero **or** `undefined` will give `NaN`, so it's probably not set. Either way, I wouldn't have the `numImages` value at all. Just pre-load the images into an array and use its length. It'll likely perform a lot better that way as well.

Comment: I will try that. I resolved the issue with the NaN. Turns out I was passing numImages as a string rather than an number. 
<React360 dir="awair-360" numImages="55" />  vs <React360 dir="awair-360" numImages={55} />

Comment: The example in codesandbox does not work in Google Chrome.